# How to make an array with dynamic variable key name

Tags: php

I have a form with a dynamic field name

for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="result.php?r=1542967950">
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="name 1">
        <input type="text" name="user[first][name][]" value="user first name 1">
        <input type="text" name="user[last][name][]" value="user last name 1">
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="name 2">
        <input type="text" name="user[first][name][]" value="user first name 2">
        <input type="text" name="user[last][name][]" value="user last name 2">
        <button type="submit">go</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The field name was generated by setting, If I dump post stuff it will like:

```
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "name 1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "name 2"
  }
  ["user"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["first"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "user first name 1"
        [1]=>
        string(17) "user first name 2"
      }
    }
    ["last"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "user last name 1"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "user last name 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is make a new array, and the structure is like:

```
$datas[0]['name'] = 'name 1';
$datas[0]['user']['first']['name'] = 'first name 1';
$datas[0]['user']['last']['name'] = 'first name 1';
$datas[1]['name'] = 'name 2';
$datas[1]['user']['first']['name'] = 'first name 2';
$datas[1]['user']['last']['name'] = 'first name 2';

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "name 1"
    ["user"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["first"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "first name 1"
      }
      ["last"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "first name 1"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "name 2"
    ["user"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["first"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "first name 2"
      }
      ["last"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "first name 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PHP will parse the field with [] symbol in field name, for avoid wrong result the way I think is to make form name like `<input type="text" name="user-first-name[]" value="user first name 1">`, but I cant't figure out the last procedure 
 to make `user-first-name` to `$data[$i]['user']['first']['name']`,

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Why you want to have this array? How you want to get value of nested items?

Comment: I am sorry, I made my question more clear

Comment: Still very much unclear what you actually want though. _“The field name was generated by setting”_ - meaning what exactly? You can’t change them? Or you want to change them, to get the data in the desired format right away? _“but I cant't figure out the last procedure to make user-first-name to $data[$i]['user']['first']['name']”_ - do you just want to split the given identifier(?) `user-first-name` into its three parts, and then generate the `['user']['first']['name']` from that dynamically? That would be rather trivial using explode, implode and a bit of string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your string to array using `explode()` and reverse it using `array_reverse()` and then use `array_reduce()` to create target structure array.

```
$str = "user-first-name";
$arr = array_reverse(explode('-', $str));
$newArr = [array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item){
    return !count($carry) ? [$item => 'value'] : [$item => $carry];
})];
```

Result

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [user] => Array
        (
          [first] => Array
            (
               [name] => value
            )

        )
    )
)
```

Check live result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/2aMHX)

Comment: But dear @Mohammead, how to turn it to `$datas['user']['first']['name'] = 'first name 1';
$data['user']['last']['name'] = 'last name 1';`

Comment: @Chan I wrapped `array_reduce` with `[]` to creating index `0` for array. So remove `[]` to removing index `0`